# Numpy reshape issues

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm


df = pd.read_csv('table.csv') 
print (df.head())

df = df[['Price', 'Asset']]
x = np.array(df.Price)
y = np.array(df.Asset)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
x, y, test_size=0.2)


x_train = np.pad(x, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
x_train.reshape((23,1))


y_train = np.pad(y, [(0,0)], mode ='constant')
y_train.reshape((23,1))

np.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/HP/Documents/linear.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Documents')
       Price     Asset
0    87.585859    191
1    87.839996    232
2    87.309998    245
3    88.629997    445
4    88.379997    393
C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: 

    DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-124-030ffa933525>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/HP/Documents/linear.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Documents')

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/HP/Documents/linear.py", line 38, in <module>
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 427, in fit
    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 520, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 176, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))

ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 23]
```

My DataFrame size: 23, 2.

I padded my x_train and y_train to [23,1] because i  got this initial error **ValueError**: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1 18].
My error message after padding: **ValueError**: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 23].

Then i tried to reshape it and still got the error message: **ValueError**: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 23].

How do i fix this?

Comment: what are you trying to reshape? `np.reshape` does not know what you want to reshape. Use it like `array.reshape((x, y))`.

Comment: As @mwormser says, you need to call `reshape` on an array object, such as `x_train` and `y_train` in your case; `x_train.reshape((23,1))`

Comment: Tried that still getting the error message: ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 23]

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. What are the sizes of `x_train` and `y_train` before padding? Did you try printing their shapes to check whether or not they are consistent? We can't run your code to test it because we don't have your data. Could you try posting a [mcve] that we can run in order to be able to reproduce your error?

Comment: @Praveen The issue has been resolved. I had to pad and reshape is what it came down to. I had to pad, because i was getting inconsistent numbers and reshape because scikit(machine learning) needs to read rows. It is also not a 1 dim array so transposing won't work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reshape an array from size `(x, 1)` to `(1, x)` you can use the `np.transpose` or `numpy.ndarray.T` function:

```
x_train = x_train.T
y_train = np.transpose(y_train)
```

Both achieve the same result.

Edit: *This only works for one-dimensional arrays. Use reshape for higher dimensional arrays.*

If you do not give us the full traceback which shows in which line the error occurs, we can't help you in more detail.

Comment: Transpose and reshape **_do not_** do the same thing! Try `a = np.arange(6).reshape((2, 3)); b = a.reshape((3, 2)); c = a.T; np.all(b == c)`. Please _try out_ your answer in future before posting it!

Comment: @Praveen Of course you are right, I was only thinking of the case where one dimensions is 1, I'll edit it.